# Access negate page is negate to anonymous user

Tags: 7, users

I have a site where only authenticated users can see the content. So I have set permission for this. Now I have a problem: I need to display a node for the access negate page. But in this moment, my access negate node is negate too.

So how can I display a node for the access negate page ? I have tried with the node view permission module, and a custom type node, without lucky.

Comment: I don't know if this might help, but what about creating a specific content-type for that? Setting the permission to allow users to read that content-type

Comment: As side note, thanks and signature are not necessary, on Stack Exchange sites.

Comment: What is what you call "access negate page"? Is it a page output from a module, or is it banally a node?